# Does a object defined in an abstract base class creates a new instance of itself on getting inherented each time?

Tags: c#, uwp

this is a conceptual question. I have an abstract base manager and I've defined a `DispatcherTimer` in my base class. I inherit my base manager by 4 more managers. The question is each time I create an instance of the `child` managers, would there be a new instance of my `Base` manager created?  And would there be 4 timers declared or would it be just the one? I know this might be a trivial question but I kinda got caught up in it.

Comment: How about adding some sample code? And yes, each 'child' will have its own instance of the timer, unless you make it a singleton.

Comment: Add some logging/debug print to the `Base` constructor and have a look - or step through in a debugger

Comment: Out of interest - why do you ask? Are all your timers firing at the same moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each new instance of the child class is also an instance of the base class so you have 4 instances of the base, each with separate timers. If you want the timer to be shared between instances, mark it as static.

**Update**

You can share a timer instance like this:

```
class Class1
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        var m1 = new Manager(timer);
        var m2 = new Manager(timer);
        var m3 = new Manager(timer);
        var m4 = new Manager(timer);
    }
}

abstract class BaseManager
{
    protected abstract void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e);

    protected BaseManager(DispatcherTimer timer)
    {
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
}

class Manager: BaseManager
{
    public Manager(DispatcherTimer timer)
    : base(timer) { }

    protected override void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you're using an IOC container, you can have a shared instance of an interface like this:

```
interface IMangerTimer
{
    DispatcherTimer Timer { get; }
}

class ManagerTimer : IMangerTimer
{
    public DispatcherTimer Timer { get; } = new DispatcherTimer();
}

abstract class BaseManager
{
    protected abstract void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e);

    protected BaseManager(IMangerTimer timer)
    {
        timer.Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
}
```

If not, just get rid of the interface and make the ManagerTimer class static.

Comment: Yes I did think about that, the issue is, it's a dispatcherTimer, and it has a Tick event which will also become static. Since the tick method calls an overriden refresh method I can not make the timer static.

Comment: Then make a single timer somewhere else and pass it to the constructors of the other objects you want to use it

Comment: @doctorlove would putting the timer in an interface reduce the instances created? Please note that the base manager is an abstract class

Comment: @AdityaSharma That would solve nothing. Interfaces are a contract, nothing more. There is no implementation associated to an interface.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The only issue is that class1 is an entry point of your entire instance creation so you can pass the timer. In my case I don't have a specific common entry point of all the managers. They are created on different pages aka views of my uwp application.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon @InBetween's answer, and adding the code for adding instance to a shared list on construction.

```
public class FooBase 
{
    private static List<FooBase> _instances = new List<FooBase>();

    public FooBase()
    {
        _instanves.Add(this);
    }
}

public class Foo: FooBase { }
```

The default constructor for `Foo` will implicitly call the default constructor of `FooBase`, which adds the current instance to the list.

Maintaining the list as object go out of scope can be trickier.  The easiest way would be to add a method to explicitly remove the instance, but you have to be very strict about always calling it.  Another option is to implement `IDisposable` and remove the instance there, but that can open a whole bunch of issues.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you are expanding my answer. I most definitely wouldn't recomend using a static field or list to solve this problem. The way I'd do this is injecting the timer (or a timer provider) in the constructor.

Comment: So the list would be created only once even if the base gets inherented as many times

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yes, exactly.  Then your timer can be static also, and have access to the list of `FooBase` to loop through.  You can then call whatever you want on each individual `FooBase`.  This probably isn't the best way to do this though, I would probably not recommend doing it. This is just to illustrate what is possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, you would not recommend me going for static right? You would recommend I use the way you've illustrated in your answer. PS: making the timer static is not an option at all. It'll spoil the entire flow of my library. Your list answer has the list as static

Comment: I wouldn't recommend directly using anything in this answer.  I just wrote this up to show you one way to access all the instances of a class from inside a static method.  I don't know enough about your architecture to make any good recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following code:

```
public class FooBase { }
public class Foo: FooBase { }
```

Now when you do the following:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

Only *one* instance is created. Now, because inheritance is a *"is a"* relationship, the following assignment is valid:

```
FooBase fooAsBase = foo;
```

Do keep in mind, that when a new `Foo` is created, all the logic needed to create a `FooBase` is also run but that does not mean two distinct objects are produced; in `new Foo()`, the parameterless constructor in `Foo` implicilty calls the parameterless constructor in `FooBase`.

UPDATE: Based on your comments, lets develop the example a bit more:

```
public class FooBase
{
    Bar someField = new Bar();
}

public class Foo: FooBase { }
```

Now, given the following code:

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();
```

`foo1` will hold a reference to a `Bar` object and `foo2` will hold it own reference to a completely different `Bar` object.

Comment: So if I have 4 child managers inheriting from the single abstract base manager then 4 dispatcherTimers would be created? Each having its own implementation for Tick event?

Comment: @AdityaSharma How many types inherit form your base class is irrelevant. You'll have as many `dispatcherTimers` as instances of child managers you create (unless `dispatcherTimers` is static of course). See update to my answer.

Comment: Yes marking it static did come to my mind but the issue is a static timer would have a static tick event. And each child manager needs to have it's own implementation of the tick event. That's why my timer is in an abstract base manager and on its tick event it calls and abstract method.

Comment: @AdityaSharma I never said static was a good idea. If you need a common timer for all created objects, then do not use a static field. Simply pass the timer as a constructor argument.

Comment: You *could* work around that by adding a static list of `FooBase` inside `FooBase` that contains a reference to each instance created in the constructor.  Then the timer can just loop through the list and call that instance's code.    You would have to have some mechanism to remove those instances when they go out of scope or are otherwise done with them though.  As @InBetween mentioned, this may not be a *good* idea, depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: It has been recommended is some other comments as well, I am not sure how to do that. Because no child managers interact with each other and provided I create a timer in a global app scope I don't seem to find a better implementation for this solution.

Comment: I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42349307/526724) showing how to add instances to a static list